# Magento search engine

Tags: magento, search

My website is http://www.godaam.com. I want to improve my search functionality. I did some changes in magento app code, but I am not able to improve it a lot. Is there any free search engine for my product I can incorporate in Magento, please help me out here?

Answer (score 0):

The magento built-in search is pretty good and you just need to tweak the settings. Do this:

- Make sure only the attributes such as **SKU, Title, Description and Quick Description** are enabled for searching (unless you need others like color etc needed)
- Tweak search settings in **System > Configuration > Catalog > Catalog Search**.
- Rebuild the indexes and test it out.

Comment: Magento CE built-in search is pathetic when your products increased and you have more then traffic.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience FULLTEXT search returns more relevant results in comparison to "LIKE" or the "COMBINED" option.

Comment: This answer appears to relate to specific database commands, rather than the search engines the question asks about.

Answer (score 0):

One of the features lacking most from Magento's search is refinement. If you search for multiple terms, it will return a bigger set of products rather than smaller. Our free extension fixes that, just a note: in order for it to work you must set the search config settings to LIKE and not FULLTEXT:

[Catalog Search Refinement FREE](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/catalog-search-refinement-free.html)